# php xml parsing with uri

Tags: php, xml-parsing

how to parse the following xml code ? i am trying the following :
echo $xml[0]->entry[0]->content[0]; but i get null value

```
<entry>
    <id>https://api.datamarket.azure.com/Data.ashx/MRC/MicrosoftAcademic/v2/Author(101612)</id>
    <category term="MRC.MicrosoftAcademic.Author" scheme="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/scheme" />
    <link rel="edit" title="Author" href="Author(101612)" /><title />
    <updated>2014-05-26T12:45:01Z</updated>
    <author>
    <name />
    </author>
    <content type="application/xml">
    <m:properties>
    <d:ID m:type="Edm.Int32">101612</d:ID>
    <d:Name>Omar Abou Khaled</d:Name>
    <d:NativeName m:null="true" />
    <d:Affiliation>University of Applied Sciences of Western Switzerland</d:Affiliation>
    <d:AffiliationID m:type="Edm.Int32">0</d:AffiliationID>
    <d:Email m:null="true" />
    <d:Homepage>http://omar.aboukhaled.home.hefr.ch/</d:Homepage>
    <d:Version m:type="Edm.Int32">11024</d:Version>
    <d:LinkedInUrl m:null="true" />
    <d:WikipediaUrl m:null="true" />
    <d:TwitterUserName m:null="true" />
    <d:ResearchInterests m:null="true" />
    </m:properties>
    </content>
</entry>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are parsing this xml using simplexml

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file(__DIR__ . '/file.xml');
```

**enty** is root node. So to get **content** node - direct call to content should be used:

```
print_r($xml->content);
```

To get content type:

```
print_r($xml->content['type']);
```

And so on.

Link left by Jay in comment is very useful.

Also there could be an error about namespaces, to quickly eliminate it, just update the root node like:

```
<entry xmlns:m="/" xmlns:d="/">
```

Comment: it shows this error : Trying to get property of non-object in C:\wamp\www\mas\test.php on line 5

Comment: Could you please share the code from test.php file (I guess the issue can be not correct path to the xml file)